# Refactor: Generating a unique slug for a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, refactoring

I'm currently generating url slugs dynamically for my models (and implementing to_param/self.from_param to interpret them). My slug generation code feels verbose, and could use a refactor.

How would you refactor this so that it is still readable, but less verbose and perhaps more clear?

**Relationships**

*User* has_many :lists

*List* belongs_to :owner

**Code**

```
def generate_slug
  if self.owner
    slug_found = false
    count      = 0
    temp_slug  = to_slug

    until slug_found
      # increment the count
      count += 1

      # create a potential slug
      temp_slug = if count > 1
        suffix = "_" + count.to_s
        to_slug + suffix
      else
        to_slug
      end

      # fetch an existing slug for this list's owner's lists
      # (i.e. owner has many lists and list slugs should be unique per owner)
      existing = self.owner.lists.from_param(temp_slug)

      # if it doesn't exist, or it exists but is the current list, slug found!
      if existing.nil? or (existing == self)
        slug_found = true
      end
    end

    # set the slug
    self.slug = temp_slug
  else
    Rails.logger.debug "List (id: #{self.id}, slug: #{self.slug}) doesn't have an owner set!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe do this

```
def generate_slug
  return Rails.logger.debug "List (id: #{self.id}, slug: #{self.slug}) doesn't have an owner set!" if !self.owner

  count = 1
  begin
    temp_slug = %Q!#{to_slug}#{"_#{count}" if count > 1}!
    existing = self.owner.lists.from_param(temp_slug)

    if existing.nil? or (existing == self)
      self.slug = temp_slug
    end
  end while count += 1
end
```

But there is two things. First you have an infinite loop which is not good. Secondly, instead of looping to check each time if the object exists and that you need to increase your suffix, you better get the last existing list and add just one after that.

Comment: The problem with getting just the last existing, is if one is deleted (and it will since content is deletable by userbase) there are gaps. Seems to me if someone creates the first one, makes a second with the same name (and thus a _2 appended to the slug), but then deletes the first, now the slug without a suffix is not available.

Comment: I don't think it is that bad to have gaps. Maybe you can rely on an other parameter to be sure it's the last one.